# Netgear Router missing Wireless Configuration Menu Link

Tags: router, wifi, netgear, configuration

I have a netgear wi-fi router DG834G v3. On it it says it's a wi-fi, adsl 2+ modem, switch, etc. There is an antena on the back and a wi-fi indicator on the front. However, when I connect to it via the web interface, the wireless setup link is missing from the menu. The top label indicates it is a DG834 (without G). I have received it from a friend and was really looking forward to using it but I really need the wi-fi part.

I looked on Netgear's site as I thought someone must have uploaded the wrong firmware for the device sometime - so I upgraded to the latest firmware, but it still says it's NOT a 'G' device and the wireless menu is nowhere to be found.

I'd appreciate a push in the right direction as to what I could do. Is it possible that the wi-fi chip is broken or something and the device does not detect it and the firmware reverts the device to a differen version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly sounds odd, NetGear do make non-wireless versions of the DG834 but if your has the antenna then it should be fine.

I think you might get more help on superuser.com or by contacting NetGear themselves, I used to have one of their boxes at home and their suppor was pretty good I thought.

Comment: Thanks, I found it odd too. Their knowledge base did not help so far and I was not expecting anyone to answer on New Year's eve. Only explanation I have for now is the device is broken in someway. Last night I tried installing the firmware update 5 times - I thought maybe reverting to an order one would solve the issue but no joy. Thanks for the superuser.com tip.